# Repeated characters shows as "?" in Dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm trying of creating a relatively simple PDF

```
$pdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
$pdf->loadHtml("0000003");
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream("Test.pdf");
```

The output is coming as `0????03` instead of `0000003` (see below)

[image]

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Usually it's encoding. Are these really in UTF8?

Comment: I just wrote "0000003" to make it as simple as possible. Obviously that's in UTF8. Also if I write "0230345023", that'll come fine. This is only happening in the case of repeated characters for some reason (the repeated zeroes in this case)

Comment: I've made a copy of your code on my side and all working good. Please check that your file is in `UTF8` encoding. I mean the file with source code

Comment: If you change the double quotes around the number to single quotes does it work?

Comment: Did you save the PHP script in UTF-8 encoding as well? Are we talking about characters you actually typed in the source code yourself, or is the data actually read from somewhere else?

Comment: My bad it's not a dompdf issue in itself. I had followed the solution mentioned https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/712 here and the `$Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text)` seems to be what is causing the problem.